# Odd LEFT JOIN error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables I am trying to join together on a particular column (shared between the two). The data in these columns are supposed to represent numbers, but the data are actually characters, and some of the values are non-numeric (e.g. '2,3,4', or 'n/a'). I am ignoring the rows with non-numeric values of this column. I am treating the columns as numeric in the join because '001' must match '1', '01', '0001', etc. Inner joining them works, left outer joining them doesn't:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.ID NOT LIKE '%[^ 0-9]%'
    AND T2.ID NOT LIKE '%[^ 0-9]%'
    AND T1.ID + 0 = T2.ID + 0
-- Success!

SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.ID NOT LIKE '%[^ 0-9]%'
    AND T2.ID NOT LIKE '%[^ 0-9]%'
    AND T1.ID + 0 = T2.ID + 0
-- Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2,3,4' to data type int.
```

Why am I getting an error on the outer join but not the inner join?

P.S.: Fixing the data is **not an option**. It is not my data; I cannot touch it. I have to find a way to work with it.

EDIT: I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM

Comment: So to be clear, you are getting an error?  Or you aren't getting the data you expect?  If you are getting an error, what is the error?

Comment: What `T1.ID + 0 = T2.ID + 0` is supposed to do?  Why not simply `T1.ID = T2.ID`?

Comment: you forget "outer" in your query. SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT Outer JOIN Table2 T2 on ...

Comment: @BillGregg I added the error message.
@wdosanjos Adding zero to the column converts it to an int. Otherwise, things like differing numbers of leading zeros would prevent the columns from matching.
@BehrouzBakhtiari `OUTER` is not required in `tsql`. It is implicit in `[LEFT|FULL|RIGHT] JOIN` ([docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213228(v=sql.80).aspx))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not guarantee the order in which the conditions will be evaluated.  In your case, `T1.ID + 0 = T2.ID + 0` is being evaluated before the `NOT LIKE` conditions.

Please try the following (SQL 2012 and above):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
    ON TRY_CAST(T1.ID AS int) = TRY_CAST(T2.ID AS int)
```

SQL 2008:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID NOT LIKE '%[^ 0-9]%') T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE ID NOT LIKE '%[^ 0-9]%') T2
    ON CAST(T1.ID AS INT) = CAST(T2.ID AS INT)
```

---

**Reference**

- [TRY_CAST (T-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx)

Comment: In my actual query, there are wildcards (`%`) on both ends; I failed to add them when I wrote the example. It's fixed now. I checked my version and I'm using SQL Server 2008 :(

Comment: Thanks for the actual answer (order not guaranteed) and the solution. Your SQL 2008 solution works for my application, with the addition of `OR ID IS NULL` on Table1).

Answer (score 1):

what if you try this instead? does it do what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
   ON (isnumeric(T1.ID) = 1
      AND  isnumeric(T2.ID) = 1)
      AND try_parse(T1.ID as int) + 0 = try_parse(T2.ID as int) + 0
```

Comment: ISNUMERIC makes both queries fail, I think because it thinks a comma is valid. Either way, this probably would have worked, but I don't have access to TRY_PARSE.